# Focus is not coming in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a button in `aspx`. In its `onclientclick` I called a javascript function which is written in `JScript.js`.
Following is my javascript:

```
function ChangeBG()
{
   alert("hi");
}
```

I called this above function in button click. I had put breakpoint in javascript. But onclicking on button, alert is coming, but control is not going to breakpoint. What may be the reason for this? I am running in Internet browser. What change i can make to bring the focus to breakpoint. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

Before `alert("hi");` put the stmt `debugger;`

```
ChangeBG() 
{
  debugger; 
  alert("hi"); 
}
```

Your control will come to debug when you are in debug mode. This problem occurs when javascript is in a separate js file.

Comment: Isn't the keyword "debugger", not "debug"?

Answer (score 1):

Also do this to enable debugging in your IE browser
Go to

**Tool-->Internet Options-->Advanced**

Uncheck - *Disable script debugging ( Internet Explorer )*